# how to achieve selection on key press using mterial-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I am using the Select component from material-ui (v3), but it does not provide the functionality when a user presses a letter on keyboard, like L, it immediately jumps to that letter.
And by pressing `Enter` key, it selects that option

Anyone has got an idea how I can achieve that?

```
 <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'age',
              id: 'age-simple',
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Important: `I am using version 3.9` and not 4.x.
https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/selects/#simple-select

Comment: Maybe try onChangeText

Comment: This functionality was added for v4 (by me). My recommendation is to upgrade.

Comment: @YakkoMajuri thank you for your suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I can't upgrade yet to v4 as I am not sure what impact will it have. Is there a way I can implement it myself? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yeah well I'd trust the guy that **built** the functionality I'm suggesting hahahahah @RyanCogswell

Comment: @BurreIfort The [migration guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/) covers the impacts well.

Comment: @BurreIfort You can find the implementation in Material-UI here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L170.

Comment: @BurreIfort And you can find the tests here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/test/integration/MenuList.test.js#L417

Comment: It involved 4 pull requests of preparation reworking how focus was managed in menus and selects before adding this functionality in order to get to a point where it would perform nicely. If you want it to behave robustly, I think upgrading will be less work than trying to add this from outside the library.